# Run MacVim Inside Terminal

Tags: vim, terminal, macvim

I recently switched from Vim to MacVim because it has Ruby support, however, the separate UI is very inconvenient. Is there a way to run MacVim inside the terminal instead of `mvim` booting a separate UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to compile vim with ruby support then. You can compile MacVim with ruby support and use the terminal vim that's contained inside its package at `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/vim`. This article includes instructions on compiling MacVim with Ruby: http://connermcd.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/blogging-with-wordpress-vim-and-markdown/

Comment: Dru already has a MacVim with Ruby support baked in; it isn't necessary to recompile it.

Answer (score 7):

One option is to make a symbolic link somewhere in your path:

```
ln -s `which mvim` vim
```

This will run MacVim in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to *launch* MacVim from the command line, maybe that will get you part of the way to what you want?

[ Put this into your .profile or .zshrc file ]

```
function mvim { /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -g $*; }
```

[credit]
http://saikotroid.blogspot.com/2011/10/launching-macvim-from-command-line.html

Comment: Thanks @zero I am currently able to use `mvim` but unlike `vim`, it opens in a separate window. This takes me away from terminal and forces me to deal with external GUIs. I really wish there was an easy way to get ruby support in Vim without rebuilding.

Comment: Tried creating a symlink but didn't work...must be some dependency issue...this worked...

Answer (score 0):

If you use homebrew (as you should) then you can use a one liner to get what you want just like I did. I needed ruby support to use the command-t plugin and this is the solution that I used. Here is where I found this [solution](https://www.morethanseven.net/2011/07/31/Vim-with-ruby-support-using-homebrew/)

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/duplicates/vim.rb
```

Comment: If you're installing MacVim via Homebrew, just use the `--override-system-vim` option.